# How to swich to /dev/console

Tags: udev, virtual-console

I can use `/dev/ttyX`, but how to access `/dev/console`?

I tried to use `chvt console`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the old days, you used to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to display the `/dev/tty0` "terminal" which was the same as `/dev/console`. Nowadays, there seems to be no method to display the contents of `/dev/console`. The closest I have found is to run the `xconsole` command. Note that this command will not "switch" to `/dev/console`; it will only display data sent to `/dev/console`.

After the `xconsole` window is started (using `sudo xconsole` command), any data send to `/dev/console` will be displayed by it. For example, after the following command is run by `root` user:

```
# echo "This is a text sent to /dev/console" >/dev/console
```

the text

> This is a text sent to /dev/console

will be dislayed on the `xconsole` window.

Comment: I can't open `xconsole` as neither a normal user nor normal user with `sudo`. Is it required to open a root X session to use `xconsole`?

Comment: `sudo xconsole` works for me. The file `/dev/console` is only accessible from `root` (read and write) or `tty` (for write only operations).